# symfony 2.8 locale reseting every request

Tags: php, symfony, locale, symfony-2.8

Example:

I am trying to set locale to English:

```
public function innerPageAction(Request $request, $slug)
{        
    $request->setLocale('en');
    return $this->render('@App/Front/Default/inner.html.twig', [
        ...
    ]);
}
```

Then I get back to homepage

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $locale = $request->getLocale();
    return $this->render('@App/Front/Default/home.html.twig', [
        'locale' => $locale,
    ]);
}
```

And this returns my default locale ('lt').

My config file looks like:

```
parameters:
    locale: lt
framework:
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

I am trying to make locale sticky as it is described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html
but it seems that its setting locale always to defaultLocale. Why?

How I can achieve that when im moving from inner page to homepage, it would return "en" not default locale "lt"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->setLocale('en');
```

is only temporary meaning it is not persisted, so when you visit another page the request locale takes the default value from the configuration file, if you follow this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html#creating-a-localelistener) (same link that you provided)

```
class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface 
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered after the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 15)),
        );
    }
}
```

the onKernelRequest method is executed on every request, if the locale was set in session it is applied by using $request->setLocale($locale), this way you'll have a 'sticky' locale on every page.

Comment: I understand this, but as I said, its not working. I never get to this: $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale); and $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale)); sets locale to 'lt' all the time. And I dont understand why.

Comment: Symfony 4.3 here, I'm experiences the same problem. `$request->getLocale()` and `$request->getSession()->get('_locale')` always return the default locale, never the locale set in the url

Answer (score 0):

In your event listener's (or subscriber's) onKernelRequest need an extra line:

```
    // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
    if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
        $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        $request->setLocale($locale); // seems that it's SIGNIFICANT
    } else {
        // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
        $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
    }
```